# How to change horizontal alignment of \frac?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

Typing `\frac{W+W^*}{2}` gives a fraction in which the denominator appears to the eye to be in the wrong position. Is there a way to correct this, i.e. place the `2` in under the `+` (without using arbitrary negative spacing)?

Comment: Are you using inline-mode or display-mode?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose five possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
% no adjustment
\frac{W+W^{*}}{2}=
% push the denominator left by the width of the asterisk
\frac{W+W^{*}}{2\hphantom{^{*}}}=
% make the asterisk protrude to the right (and add a correction)
\frac{W+W^{\mathrlap{*}}}{2}\,=
% push the denominator a bit left
\frac{W+W^{*}}{\!2}=
% change the order
\frac{W^{*}+W}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably the middle one is the best, in this particular case.

Answer (score 7):

Use `\hphantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \frac{W+W^*}{2\hphantom{^{*}}}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to exploit the fact that `^{*}` is the extra parameter in `W + W`. Adding a horizontal space of extra `^{*}` to the denominator (after `2`) does the work to bring `2` to the centre of `W + W`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\hphantom{^{*}}`?

Comment: I got a different answer in another latex group: use \frac{W+W^{\rlap{$\scriptscriptstyle*$}}{2} with the slight advantage that the horizontal line only reaches until the second W. But your answer is more elegant.