# Horizontal alignment of numerator and denominator in a \frac expression

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fractions

I need to typeset the derivative of l by z_a. Normally I would do `\frac{\diff l} {\diff z_a}` with `\newcommand{\diff} {\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`.

This gives:

[image]

which does not look very good imho due to the alignment.

Following what one answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150506/how-to-change-horizontal-alignment-of-frac) suggests, I tried `\frac{\diff l\hphantom{_a}} {\diff z_a}`, which gives:

[image]

Now this looks good enough for me, but the whole thing got me wondering what the correct way to typeset derivatives is. Are there any general rules concerning the horizontal alignment? Is it maybe possible to align the d's? I guess that would probably look best and it could be used universally without having to look at every single derivative you typeset.

Comment: `\frac{\diff l\hfill} {\diff z_a}` for left alignment without the phantoms.  In general `\newcommand\lfrac[2]{\frac{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}` would work.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, I'm afraid; I'd go for centering in any case.

Comment: @egreg after playing around a bit I guess you are right in general. But I still think that there are cases where aligned d's look best :-). But then we are at the point again where we have to look at every single derivative we typeset...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As egreg pointed out, the setting of a derivative fraction is a matter of opinion, and left-aligned is not to his taste.

However, if it is still of interest to you, I shared the definition

```
\newcommand\lfrac[2]{\frac{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}
```

that would produce a left-aligned fraction, without having to manually tweak each use case.  For derivatives in particular, the `\lfrac` can be used in its own macro,

```
\newcommand\Diff[3][]{\lfrac{\diff^{#1}#2}{\diff\ifx\diff#3\else#3\fi^{#1}}}
```

What `\Diff` does is allow two syntaxes to obtain the setting of a derivative, either `\Diff{y}{x}` or alternately `\Diff{y}{\diff x}`.  The macro determines whether `\diff` has been specified at the front of the denominator and strips it if necessary.

EDITED to add optional argument to `\Diff` to allow higher-order derivative setting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\diff} {\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand\lfrac[2]{\frac{#1\hfill}{#2\hfill}}
\newcommand\Diff[3][]{\lfrac{\diff^{#1}#2}{\diff\ifx\diff#3\else#3\fi^{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\diff l} {\diff z_a}\cdot\frac{\diff Q_\mathrm{ref}}{\diff x}
\textrm{~for~comparison}
\]
\[
\lfrac{\diff l} {\diff z_a}\cdot\lfrac{\diff Q_\mathrm{ref}}{\diff x}
\textrm{~with \textbackslash lfrac}
\]
\[
\Diff{l}{z_a}     \cdot     \Diff{Q_\mathrm{ref}}{\diff x}
\textrm{~with \textbackslash Diff (2 syntaxes)}
\]
\[
\Diff[2]{l}{z_a}     \cdot     \Diff[3]{Q_\mathrm{ref}}{\diff x}
\textrm{~with \textbackslash Diff (and opt. argument)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if one likes the syntax of the `\Diff` macro, but not the left-alignment, it can be changed back to center-alignment by changing the `\lfrac` to `\frac` in the definition of `\Diff`.

Comment: Thanks, very good! But I don't fully understand how the checking for a duplicate \diff works. Doesn't \ifx\diff#3 compare \diff to argument number three? Or does it only take the first part of the argument and uses the second part as output if the comparison yields true? In that case it would work, I guess. Sorry, I'm not very familiar with latex conditionals...

Comment: @user35915 `\ifx\diff#3` compares `\diff` to the unexpanded first token of argument `#3` (note that argument 3 is the denominator, even if an optional argument is not specified).  If the test fails, the `\else` code is executed.  But if the test succeeds, the first token of `#3`, the `\diff`, was absorbed in the comparison test, leaving the rest of the `#3` tokens to be executed in case of success.  It effectively strips off the leading `\diff`.

Comment: @user35915 In the case of the `\else` code, the complete `#3` is regurgitated.  However, the else code is only executed if there was no leading `\diff`, and thus one would want the complete `#3` to be executed, in that case.